# Connect to a database through VPN using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, vpn

I'm looking to access a SQL database through a VPN in Python.

Everything has been configured on the server side. I can use Visual Studio on my laptop, configure an ODBC driver and set up an ODBC data source, and I'm able to access that database from that set up using WatchGuard Mobile as the VPN client (with credentials).

As far as Python is concerned, I should be able to connect to the database using the package `pyodbc` but I'm not sure how to connect to the VPN in the first place. I've seen the packages `openvpn-api` and also `socket`, but I'm not familiar with these so unsure whether they're actually the ones I should look at to solve that problem.

I've only been up to

```
import openvpn_api

v = openvpn_api.VPN(HOST, PORT)                                                                                                      
v.connect()

## Output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/openvpn-api/openvpn_api/vpn.py", line 73, in connect
  raise errors.ConnectError(str(e)) from None
openvpn_api.util.errors.ConnectError: timed out
```

and

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

s.recv(1024)

## Output
b'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nDate: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 18:59:29 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 138\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on whether the approach `socket` + `pyodbc` makes sense, and any help or resource on `socket` or a more appropriate package to connect to a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should have to interact with the VPN at all in Python. You should be able to connect to the VPN using the separate VPN client you have installed on your laptop. I assume this VPN connection allows you access to the network that the SQL Server is on.

Once you are connected to the VPN though the VPN client, your laptop should be able to reach the SQL Server, and through ODBC you can connect to it.

```py
import pyodc

server = 'YourSQLServerName'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}'          # depends on what driver you have installed
database = 'YourSQLDatabaseName'

# pyodbc can also list the ODBC you have installed
# drivers = pyodbc.drivers()

# trusted_connection will use your local credentials
##assuming a separate username and password isn't required (security is provided by the VPN)

connection = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=server, database=database, trusted_connection='yes')

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: Re "I assume this VPN connection allows you access to the network that the SQL Server is on". Yes that's it. I'm working for that task on AWS, the architecture I have in mind, the most interesting cost wise, would be to deal with the VPN through a script. I'm considering now using other resources though, seems that would make things simpler in the end. Thanks for the code for `pyodbc` that will be useful.